# Unable to delete a line in file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have to delete a line in a file from inside a shell script.

I am trying this:

```
linenumber=0
##CHeck If server IP exists
if grep -wq $serverip $FILE; then
        echo "IP exists"
        linenumber=$(awk -v serverip="$serverip" '$0 ~ serverip {print NR}' $FILE)
        echo "$linenumber"
        sed -e '${$linenumber}d' $FILE

fi
```

Basically I extract the line number and then want to delete it.

```
sed -e '1d' $FILE  --> WOrks on CLI but inside script does not work
```

Why? How to get it working ?

Comment: Probably you want to use `sed -i` which modifies the file instead of printing the result to stdout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply a case of using the incorrect quotes around your sed command, so the variable isn't being used. Ignoring the fact that you're unnecessarily using 3 tools when 1 would suffice, the fix is this:

```
sed -e "${linenumber}d" "$FILE"
```

Perhaps your requirement is more complex than it appears but I would suggest changing your entire script to this:

```
awk -v serverip="$serverip" '!($0 ~ serverip)' "$FILE"
```

This prints every line that doesn't contain the shell variable `$serverip`. It is assumed that you have escaped any regex meta-characters present in the variable.

Alternatively (and more succinctly):

```
sed "/$serverip/d" "$FILE"
```

If you actually want the messages to be printed out (I assumed that they were for debugging), then that's easy enough to achieve:

```
awk -v serverip="$serverip" '$0 ~ serverip { print "IP exists"; print NR; next } 1' "$FILE"
```

If you're not familiar with the `1` at the end, it's just a common shorthand which causes awk to print each line (`1` is always true and the default action is `{ print }`).

Comment: Or, sed instead of awk: `sed "/$serverip/d" "$FILE"` -- same caveat about regex metachars.

Comment: I always go for awk by default but yes, that's probably better, thanks.

Comment: I agree: as soon as I type a `;` into a sed script, I think about using a different tool.